# Estimate The Number Of Videos On Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How to estimate the number of videos hosted on Youtube?
A sample search on Google: site:www.youtube.com/watch return 1,080,000,000. By Using Youtube API gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/* and parsing  tag (goto view source for example to do that), suggested on http://beerpla.net/2008/08/14/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-videos-on-youtube/ by Artem Russakovskii return only 1.000.000. He updated the figure under the page on August 2010 to an estimated 141 million to 144 million.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Randy

Comment: Are you bored? Is this a job interview question? What's wrong with the solution you've already found and linked to?

Comment: Currently, the solution using Youtube API returns the fixed constant 1 million. Probably it is a recently introduced upper limit to the number of lines returned by the gdata query or something similar. The actual number of Youtube videos is probably around 250 million extrapolated from the Russakovskii’s August 2010 result. It is well below the 1.080 billion returned by the simple search (that probably include repetitions). I could not figure out a better method to obtain a more accurate estimative until now.

Comment: Also, the problem proposed is not job interview question like Cody Gray suggested. But perhaps someone likes the question to interview some API guy. I am developing an early prototype of an application to easily include Audio Description in Internet Video. So, I am very interested on the number of videos available on Internet vis-à-vis the number of videos with Audio Description, that are very few, probably less than 5.000 considering all languages.